# Vertically align center for a ion-card [IONIC]

Tags: ionic-framework, alignment, center, vertical-alignment

I'm developing a login form, so inside my `<ion-content padding >` I have an `<ion-card>` (used like a container of the login form) that I want to center vertically. I tried different ways with css flexbox and other css tricks but nothing worked for me! The card remains at the top of the page. 
Can you help me please?

```
<ion-card id = "login-card">
    <form [formGroup]="signInForm" (submit)="doEmailPswLogin()" class="input">
        <ion-list>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>


          <div padding>
            <button ion-button color="primary" block [disabled]="buttonDisabled">Effettua il login</button>
          </div>

        </ion-list>
      </form>
</ion-card>
```

I do not have any kind of scss acting on this page. All the tests I did were useless (the card did not move a millimeter), except using margin-top on the card, but it's not a correct way to do it, I would like to have something responsive!
Thank you in advance!

**SOLUTION**

I used this code and my card it's now centered!

```
 <ion-grid style="height: 100%">
    <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center style="height: 100%">
      <ion-card id = "login-card">
        <form >
          <ion-list>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-label fixed>Email</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="email"  name="email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="password"  name="password"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>


            <div padding>
              <button ion-button color="primary" block >Effettua il login</button>
            </div>

          </ion-list>
        </form>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Thanks your solution was useful!

Answer (score 1):

Another quick thing that can be done is setting your `scroll-content's` `display` to `flex` and `justify-content` and `align-items` to `center`.